# Resolution Issue on Retina Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro, display-resolution

I've tried so many solutions, I'm officially out of ideas to resolve the display issues on my mac. Everything is very tiny. I'm running out of Parallels. I have the retina option enabled and everything is clear at max res, but also very very very tiny. I open sublime and I can barely see anything. Is there is a fix for this? I'm running 14.10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thought there would have been a HiDPI setting in the Unity Tweak Tool, but I can't find anything. I'm running Gnome on my Ubuntu installation, and found that the Gnome Tweak Tool has a HiDPI setting where you can scale up to your heart's content. My Macbook isn't retina, so I cannot confirm that this will work with complete certainty, but it might if you're willing to try out Gnome.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-tweak-tool
```

Choose LightDM when prompted. When complete, log out and you will now find a small icon to the right of your username on the login screen. Clicking that icon will offer a choice of shell to use. So, select Gnome, and login. Then run "gnome-tweak-tool" from the command line or find it in the applications, which popup with CMD+A.

From the Gnome Tweak Tool, select the "Windows" section on the left side-pane, where HiDPI is the last entry on the right.

If this works for you, at least you have a solution until someone writes a HiDPI setting for Unity. And at any time you can switch back and forth between Gnome and Unity, so you don't have to commit to anything.