# Application resolution problems with Macbook Pro retina

Tags: 16.04, macbook, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook pro retina mid 2014. Everything was smooth until this issue. Some applications resolution are too small to read including buttons, texts etc.

Here are the screenshot:

[image: picture]

[image: picture]

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/650388/resolution-issue-on-retina-macbook-pro

Comment: It doesn't work for my case. I followed it and nearly ruin my system.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution for my case. Just post here if someone needs it.

Very simple, open System Setting > Displays

Then change the resolution to the lower ones until it perfectly fit your screen.

Maybe change the scale for better results.

Hope this helps!